# Wildfly truststore and axis

Tags: java, ssl, wildfly, apache-axis, truststore

A background process active on my Wildfly 10.0.0.Final needs to connect to a webservice using Axis. On the remote server, there is a self-signed certificate, which I imported in a truststore using openssl to get it from the remote server and they keytool to create the truststore and import the certificate into it.

I set up my Wildfly 10.0.0.Final's standalone.xml like this:

```xml
<security-realm name="SSLRealm">
    <server-identities>
        <ssl>
            <keystore path="keystore.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"
                            keystore-password="mykeystorepassword" alias="myalias"
                            key-password="mykeypass" />
        </ssl>
        </server-identities>
            <authentication>
                <truststore path="truststore.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"
                        keystore-password="mytruststorepassword" />
            </authentication>
</security-realm>

<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" />
    <https-listener name="default-ssl" security-realm="SSLRealm" socket-binding="https" />
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
        <location name="/" handler="welcome-content" />
    </host>
</server>
```

but still, when the background process tries to connect to the remote service, I obtain the following exception:

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea how to solve this issue? It seems like the truststore is not being used or something like this...

Comment: 1) is `myalias` the correct alias in the `jks` file? 2) is `truststore.jks` in the `Wildfly` folder (i.e. not a subfolder) 3) is the self-signed cert in the `cacerts` file within the `JDK` of the client?

Comment: 1) yes it is; 2) yes it is; 3) Mmm... no, it doesn't. I thought about the cacerts as well, but I thought that Wildfly wouldn't use it, but the truststore indicated in the standalone.xml. I will give it a try

Comment: at the end, I had to add the self-signed certificate to the cacerts, but, as @chris-c points out in the answer below, I don't get why the trust store in the security realm is ignored...

Comment: The security-realm is to authenticate *inbound* connections.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and could only solve it by adding parameters to the startup script for wildfly:

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=foo.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=bar

which, of course, overrides the default cacerts.
But I am unclear why the truststore defined in the security-realm seems to be ignored.